# How do I change my $EDITOR variable if it refuses to change?

Tags: linux, kde, environment-variables, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro Linux in the KDE Plasma desktop environment. I'd like to be able to use the classic C-X C-E command to run Vim from a terminal emulator running Bash on the GUI desktop. However, when I try to change $EDITOR from `/usr/bin/nano` to `/usr/bin/vim` in my ~/.bash_profile, it fails to change in terminal emulators running on the GUI desktop. What could cause this, and how could I change it?

In the virtual consoles, it works fine. I execute `$ echo $EDITOR` and the expected `/usr/bin/vim` appears. Other environment variables changed and added in .bash_profile appear as expected in terminal emulators on the desktop and in the virtual consoles, e.g. `$ echo SDL_SOUNDFONTS` returns `/path/to/foo.sf2`.

When I execute `$ export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` or `$ EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim; export EDITOR` in a terminal emulator on the GUI desktop, the environment variable changes as expected to `/usr/bin/vim`. Likewise, if I add `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` or `EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim; export EDITOR` to my .bashrc, then `$ echo EDITOR` returns `/usr/bin/vim` as expected in terminal emulators on the GUI desktop.

However, I've seen it said that environment variables should be modified in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile, or even in /etc for variables set globally, but not in ~/.bashrc, which is why I've focused on ~/.bash_profile.

At this point, I just want to satisfy my curiosity: What in the desktop environment could be changing $EDITOR to `/usr/bin/nano` over the instructions in my ~/.bash_profile? As far as I can tell, my .bashrc isn't the culprit, but I'm a new user and could easily have missed something important.

Comment: Silly question - after you modified `~/.bash_profile`, did you log out and back in?  It only gets evaluated by login-shells, which the terminals you open on your desktop **aren't**.  Or you could force them to be login-shell by editing your desktop short-cut to include `-l` as a parameter.

Comment: If people are telling you that environment variables shouldn't be set in ~/.bashrc then either you're misinterpreting what they said/wrote, or they don't know what they're talking about. `~/.bash_profile` is for stuff you want to happen when you start a login shell.  `~/.bashrc` is for stuff you want to happen in non-login shells.   BTW, it's not at all uncommon to `source ~/.bashrc` in ~/.bash_profile - in fact, that's often recommended so you can avoid duplicating the code that sets your environment variables....in effect, this makes .bash_profile for login-only stuff, and .bashrc for both

Comment: @tink Yes, I did. This updated the environment variables I had set in my `~/.bash_profile`, but, for some reason, not $EDITOR.

Comment: @cas Changing $EDITOR in `~/.bashrc` is a practical solution to the problem. Thanks for the tip about sourcing `~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile`. But why wouldn't changing it in `~/.bash_profile`, which changes other environment variables, change $EDITOR upon a reboot or a new login?

Comment: dunno.  it should, ~/.bash_profile is sourced by bash login shells - that's what it's for.   is your terminal emulator not forking shells with `-l` or something? (that's often an option that can be enabled or disabled in many terminal programs, check the config and see if it has an option for login vs non-login shell)

Comment: @stanley_gibbon_87 What no one is telling you is that you should read the INVOCATION section of the bash man page so that you actually understand when each of the various initialization files is read.

Comment: @Marc Wilson I understand that upon login, bash first looks for /etc/profile and executes what it finds there; that it then looks for and executes ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile, whichever it finds first; and that it executes ~/.bashrc with non-login interactive shells. The issue is that it should find `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim` in ~/.bash_profile upon login and change the editor accordingly, and in the virtual consoles, it does, but in the desktop environment, it fails to do this. This is not addressed, as far as I can tell, in `man bash`.

Comment: @cas As far as I can tell from ~/.config/yakuakerc, ~/.config/konsolerc, and ~/.config/terminator/config, all of which programs exhibit this strange behavior, nothing in these programs insists on not forking shells with `-l`. In any case, `-l` in Terminator changes the layout, not the program's login status. I suspect a KDE program is insisting that `$EDITOR` should equal `/usr/bin/nano`.

Comment: @stanley_gibbon_87 you're confusing Terminator's own `-l` option with the options terminator uses when it runs $SHELL.    They're two entirely different and separate things.  e.g. `bash` starts a non-login shell.  `bash -l` starts a login shell.    In xfce4-terminal, under Edit -> Preferences -> General tab, there's a checkbox for "Run command as login shell"....it's been years since I used Terminator, but it probably has a similar setting.

Comment: @cas You're right, of course. I don't see anything in the Preferences for Terminator, Yakuake, or Konsole that would obviously run `bash -l`, but I'm new, so I might be missing something. I'll consult the man pages.